# QGIS Plugin Syntax error

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have started a plugin using the 'minimal plugin' and have added my code in but am getting an error, the code is as follows:

```
from qgis.core import Qgis, QgsProject, QgsWkbTypes, QgsVectorLayer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox

def classFactory(iface):
    return MinimalPlugin(iface)


class MinimalPlugin:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface

    def initGui(self):
        self.action = QAction('Go!', self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)

    def unload(self):
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
        del self.action

    def run(self):
        lyr_name = 'Individual Trees'
        out_path = 'C:\\Users\\MatthewWhitehead\\OneDrive - Innovative Forestry Ltd\\Arboricultural Reports\\Tree Condition Survey\\Tree_Condition_Ind_Export.xlsx'

        lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(lyr_name)[0]

        wkb = QgsWkbTypes.displayString(lyr.wkbType())
        crs = lyr.crs().authid()
        tmp_lyr = QgsVectorLayer(f'{wkb}?crs={crs}', f'{lyr_name}', 'memory')
        tmp_lyr.dataProvider().addAttributes(lyr.fields())
        tmp_lyr.updateFields()
        tmp_lyr.dataProvider().addFeatures([f for f in lyr.selectedFeatures()])

        processing.run("native:exporttospreadsheet",
            {'LAYERS':[tmp_lyr],
            'USE_ALIAS':False,
            'FORMATTED_VALUES':False,
            'OUTPUT':out_path,
            'OVERWRITE':True})

    
        QMessageBox.information(None, 'Minimal plugin', 'Do something useful here')
```

My error is showing on line 11:

> **init**.py", line 11
> from qgis.core import Qgis, QgsProject, QgsWkbTypes,, QgsVectorLayer
> ^
> SyntaxError: trailing comma not allowed without surrounding parentheses

Is this due to incorrect parent at start?

Comment: Are you sure the code you show here is the same that throws an error? Because the errror message shows two commas directly after each other (`,,`), but your code does not contain such a line

Comment: apologies, loaded wrong error message, here is the one thrown up:

'2022-11-08T13:37:56     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\Users/MatthewWhitehead/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Minimal\__init__.py", line 38, in run
              lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(lyr_name)[0]
             IndexError: list index out of range'